# Automatically Download Latest SQL Server CU/SP?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a `PowerShell` script to automatically install sql server, and I added functionality to install updates along with the base installation. Right now I'm just putting the download link for the update into the `WebClient.DownloadFile()` method, but I know of a way to programatically find the download links for specific updates. I'd prefer to not hardcode download links into the script in case they change on the download site, but right now I have to.

Is there a more concrete/standard way of downloading SQL Server updates, or just consistently finding the downloads?

Comment: [Bent Ozar](https://sqlserverupdates.com/) has a site that he lists the updates on. You can click on the "Other Updates" to ge the list and download links. But I'm kind of shocked you are using a script to download and install and update sql server. I guess downtime isn't an issue for you, and you don't care what the update includes. Hopefully this is for a dev environment :) There is also the [official catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=sql%20server) you could scrape.

Comment: This is for production, but only for new installs, not on live servers. Looks like scraping the official site is best. Thank you!